# Is there any query to find this id information?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

Her is a sample of my table:

```
+--------+-------+-----+
|  name  | value | id  |
+--------+-------+-----+
| value1 |     1 | 100 |
| value2 |     2 | 100 |
| value1 |     1 | 200 |
| value2 |     3 | 200 |
| value1 |     1 | 300 |
| value2 |     4 | 300 |
|        |       |     |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

How to setup an SQL query to retrieve the `id` value 100 for given `value1 = 1` and `value2 = 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by id and set the condition in the having clause:

```
select id
from tablename
where (name, value) in (('value1', 1), ('value2', 2))
group by id
having count(distinct value) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kFwFYkv7AdSja6rJincyD6/0).

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, aggregation with a `having` clause does what you want:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(*) filter (where name = 'value1' and value = 1) = 1 and
       count(*) filter (where name = 'value2' and value = 2) = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division). See:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

This query typically *more efficient* than what has been suggested so far:

```
SELECT id
FROM  (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE name = 'value1' AND value = 1) t1
JOIN  (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE name = 'value2' AND value = 2) t2 USING (id);
```

Or equivalent (results in identical query plan):

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (id)
WHERE  t1.name = 'value1' AND t1.value = 1
AND    t2.name = 'value2' AND t2.value = 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2e1fb4b66a36f58dcbabb78458741fe1)*

Not enforcing uniqueness in the query (like other answers do) as I assume one or more constraints in the table already doing so.

Have a "covering" index on `(name, value, id)`. Optimized index variations are possible, depending on your undisclosed table definition.

But first reconsider your relational design if you are in a position to change it. EAV models are typically sub-optimal. See:

- [Is there a name for this database schema of key values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20763/3684)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id from TABLE_NAME WHERE value IN (1, 2);

This is will retrieve the *id* column from your table when *value* column is either 1 or 2